# External URL must include a FQDN

Tags: gitlab

I set up a fresh CentOS 6.6 install and used the Omniubus installer for the CE of Gitlab.

When running **gitlab-ctl reconfigure** I get the following errors:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


RuntimeError
------------
External URL must include a FQDN


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/gitlab.rb:95:in `parse_external_url'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/gitlab.rb:191:in `generate_config'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:34:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/gitlab.rb:

 88:  
 89:      def parse_external_url
 90:        return unless external_url
 91:  
 92:        uri = URI(external_url.to_s)
 93:  
 94:        unless uri.host
 95>>         raise "External URL must include a FQDN"
 96:        end
 97:        Gitlab['user']['git_user_email'] ||= "gitlab@#{uri.host}"
 98:        Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_host'] = uri.host
 99:        Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_email_from'] ||= "gitlab@#{uri.host}"
100:  
101:        case uri.scheme
102:        when "http"
103:          Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_https'] = false
104:        when "https"
```

The FQDN of the server is correctly set, I have an external IP. DNS is configured for the FQDN to point at my external IP.

Here's the contents of my ***/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb*** in case that is useful:

```
# Check and change the external_url to the address your users will type in their browser
external_url 'gitlab.thefallenphoenix.net'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@thefallenphoenix.net'
```

Comment: postet on october, now middle december, the bug still exists. I don´t get it how they can release software which isn´t even installable

Comment: This bug also appears from the default install of Digital Ocean's GitLab "One Click Install" app Droplet option on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is now fixed with adding `http://` or `https://` to the domain in the `.rb` file. Tested on Debian 9 with Gitlab EE.

---

Add a `=` sign to the *gitlab.rb*.

It should be:

```
external_url = 'gitlab.thefallenphoenix.net'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@thefallenphoenix.net'
```

After that it should install fine. At least it worked for me on CentOS 6.6.

Comment: Strange that I needed to add that as apart from the 2nd line the file was the default one!

Comment: @kemra102 If that's the case consider opening an issue upstream.

Comment: Just had same issue, did not notice the missing equals sign! Definitely an issue with omnibus, can someone more in the know notify upstream?

Comment: This solution worked for me!  I the same problem (I'm also using omnibus, with the default gitlab.rb untouched), except I'm using CentOS 7 rather than 6.6

Comment: Actually this is just to make the script shut up. The script just ignores this - as soon as you want to change anything in the url it doesnt work. see JusticeO's answer for a real solution

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, for those arriving from Google. You need to add `http://` or `https://` to the external url var in the `.rb` file instead. See the answer below for more information. This solved my debian stretch issues with this same error.

Answer (score 18):

Adding the equal (=) sign to the gitlab.rb only solves your problem temporarily! It is not a bug. 
Using "http://example.com" instead of "example.com" actually solved the problem. 
*If gitlab installs fine but not accessible via browser, add a port to the url like "http://example.com:10080" and you should be seeing the website http://example.com:10080 in your browser

Comment: This is a long term solution, it worked for me as the other accepted answer didn't. Thanks!

Comment: where and how can I change this ?

Comment: go to /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb (omnibus gitlab)

Comment: how can I do this if I run gitlab in docker container? The container fails before I can log onto it...

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade from 6.6.9 to latest gitlab_7.4.3-omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1_amd64.deb

just follow the upgrade [instruction](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md) before the

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

vim /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/libraries/gitlab.rb

```
 99     def parse_external_url
100       return unless external_url
101
102       uri = URI("http://whatever.example.com")
          //just change external_url line here 
103
104       unless uri.host
105         raise "External URL must include a FQDN"
106       end
107       Gitlab['user']['git_user_email'] ||= "gitlab@#{uri.host}"
108       Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_host'] = uri.host
109       Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_email_from'] ||= "gitlab@#{uri.host}"
110
111       case uri.scheme
112       when "http"
113         Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_https'] = false
114       when "https"
115         Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_https'] = true
116         Gitlab['nginx']['ssl_certificate'] ||= "/etc/gitlab/ssl/#{uri.host}.crt"
117         Gitlab['nginx']['ssl_certificate_key'] ||= "/etc/gitlab/ssl/#{uri.host}.key"
118       else
119         raise "Unsupported external URL scheme: #{uri.scheme}"
120       end
121
122       unless ["", "/"].include?(uri.path)
123         raise "Unsupported external URL path: #{uri.path}"
124       end
125
126       Gitlab['gitlab_rails']['gitlab_port'] = uri.port
127     end
```

and then do

```
gitlab-ctr reconfigure
```

everything is ok!

Comment: external url is configurable at /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
So just open up /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and add http:// in external_url variable to make this work.

Comment: I downvoted this option since it is not recommended to change the code if its possible to edit it via a config file.